# Nested if statements - how to refactor conditions to use one if statement while iterating

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects:

```
var contacts = [
  {
      "firstName": "Akira",
      "lastName": "Laine",
      "number": "0543236543",
      "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
      "firstName": "Harry",
      "lastName": "Potter",
      "number": "0994372684",
      "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
      "firstName": "Sherlock",
      "lastName": "Holmes",
      "number": "0487345643",
      "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  },
  {
      "firstName": "Kristian",
      "lastName": "Vos",
      "number": "unknown",
      "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];
```

I have written a function to iterate over them.

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {  

  for ( i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {  
    if (contacts[i].firstName === name) {  
      if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {                     
        return contacts[i][prop]     
      } else {
        return "No such property"; 
      }
    }
  }

return "No such contact"; 

}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes"));
```

I have attempted to restructure the function, so rather than using two nested if statements I can use one if statement and the AND operator. Why have I done this to improve readability as I find nested ifs hard to read. When I do though I don't get the expected return value - I get 'No such property' when the object definitely exists. So in other words why is the second function not working correctly? have I broken the way the function iterates?

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {  

  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {  
    if (contacts[i].firstName === name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {                 
      return contacts[i][prop]     
    } else {
      return "No such property"; 
    }
  }
  return "No such contact"; 
}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes"));
```

Comment: Please, just **stop** deleting the question, it's the **third time you post it**. Allow people to answer you, **your question is valid and looks fair, you have provided enough informations to address your issue, don't delete it again**. Just **STOP** deleting the question over and over. The problem is still the same, in the second code, where if the first if statement fails for **whatever element** it **returns**, that's it.

Comment: Not my fault my question keeps getting edited. Easier to start again so I can have a clean post and is not a complete mess. I am not posting it again and again hoping for a different answer.

Comment: That's fine, now, let's focus to the real problem: as you can see, in your second code, you have an if statement that, if for whatever reason fails, it **returns**. That's it. In the second case, if the first element (for example) fails, the whole loop is stopped. In the first case, if the first element (for example) fails, the loop continues, that's how it's different :).

Comment: With this kind of loop, having two separate if statements is the most efficient way to find a property, since it allows for early return.

Comment: Okay then is there a way to utilise the && operator to addess this problem? I would rather not use nested statements

Comment: @user1554264 why are you trying to fix something that isn't broken?

Comment: @user1554264 technically, you should just remove the else statement and return `"No such contact or property"` instead of "No such contact". because with a single if statement you have a sort of information loss. That would be the fastest and cleverest solution, unless you need to track whether the contact exists and the property doesn't.

Comment: @kobe Clearly the second function is broken - does not return the properties of the given object.

Comment: @user1554264 your first function is the best way to approach the issue.

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation as to why? I don't like the readability of nested statements and actually find them very diifcult to read. This is why I was attempting to convert it to one line.

Comment: What is the reason that you want to get rid of one if statement? You have one condition to find an object and a second one to verify that the found object is valid. You won’t get any benefit in readability or performance if you try to merge them into one condition. You more likely would like to move the inner condition out of the loop because it will always only be called once for the first found element.

Comment: "my question keeps getting edited" by others? And in what way? Deletion however is the wrong reaction anyways.

Comment: @user1554264 : if either of the answers below solved your problem, you may accept that to help that solution being notice by the others facing the same issue. And, I guess, it's worth noticing ;) that my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56904556/11299053) is the most compact among provided while running [just as fast](https://jsperf.com/lkjoiuwera) as top voted one.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you're trying to do 2 things.

1. Find the right object from an array by first name.
2. Determine if that object has a specific property, and if so return its value.

For that, having a nested `if` makes sense. 2 bits of logic, 2 `if` statements.

You can of course refactor it to not use nested ifs, first try to find the object and then check if that object has the required property:

```js
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {  
  var obj = contacts.find(c => c.firstName === name);
  if(!obj)
     return "No such contact";
     
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
     return obj[prop];
     
  return "No such property";
}


var contacts = [
  {
      "firstName": "Akira",
      "lastName": "Laine",
      "number": "0543236543",
      "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
      "firstName": "Harry",
      "lastName": "Potter",
      "number": "0994372684",
      "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
      "firstName": "Sherlock",
      "lastName": "Holmes",
      "number": "0487345643",
      "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  },
  {
      "firstName": "Kristian",
      "lastName": "Vos",
      "number": "unknown",
      "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];


console.log(lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes")); 
console.log(lookUpProfile("Harry", "foo")); 
console.log(lookUpProfile("Bob", "likes"));
```

Comment: I don’t understand that either, especially because your answer shows how that code should be refactored to be read- and maintainable. The inner if does not belong into the loop, because it will always break the loop when it is evaluated. One could argue about the coding style but that’s nitpicking and opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

The second function doesn't work properly because here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {  
    if (contacts[i].firstName === name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {                 
      return contacts[i][prop]     
    } else {
      return "No such property"; 
    }
  }
```

if the first if fails, the code `return`. So, because it returns, whenever an item fails the if no other items are processed, which is different from your first function.

If you want to keep your current for loop and just return whether the contact exists or not (and an eventual property), you can keep track whether the contact exists or not and return the error accordingly.

Please note that this can be accomplished in shorter and better ways, I'm just trying to keep your code as it currently is, without the double if statement you don't want to use.

```js
var contacts = [
  {
      "firstName": "Akira",
      "lastName": "Laine",
      "number": "0543236543",
      "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
      "firstName": "Harry",
      "lastName": "Potter",
      "number": "0994372684",
      "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
      "firstName": "Sherlock",
      "lastName": "Holmes",
      "number": "0487345643",
      "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  },
  {
      "firstName": "Kristian",
      "lastName": "Vos",
      "number": "unknown",
      "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];

function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {  
  var contactExists = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    contactExists = contactExists || contacts[i].firstName === name;
    if (contactExists && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {                 
      return contacts[i][prop];
    }
  }
  return contactExists ? "No such property" : "No such contact"; 
}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes")); 
console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "S")); 
console.log(lookUpProfile("Nothing", "Hey"));
```

Comment: You removed the `if` keyword so yes that's what the OP asked. But to be fair `contactExists = contactExists || contacts[i].firstName === name;` is like `contactExists ? "No such property" : "No such contact"` just a shadowed `if` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue with your second code example is that no matter what your condition in your `if` statement evaluates to, you will always `return` from your function, thus stopping the loop after its first iteration.

If you wish to not have nested statements, you can create a variable, which defines what message you'll return (ie: whether you should return `"No such property"` or `"No such contact"`) once your loop is complete. Thus, instead of returning from within your loop, you can change the variable within the loop such that it represents what you will return once it is complete.

For example:

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {  
  let msg = "No such contact"; // default message
  for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    let hasProp = contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop);
    if (contacts[i].firstName === name && hasProp) {                 
      return contacts[i][prop];     
    } else if(!hasProp) {
      msg = "No such property"; // change the value of the message to return
    }
  }
  return msg; // if we reach this point, we must've not returned earlier in the loop, so we can output the message
}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes"));
```

However, by using nested `if` statements, you'll allow your code to `return` earlier than the above code (ie: the entire loop doesn't need to run) thus making your code more efficient.

Comment: That not only changes the early out situation but also the logic of the code. The code of the OP requires that a found object has the give property. Your code only requires that one of the matching objects has the property.

Comment: @t.niese ah, thanks, I think I see what you're saying. I've changed my code a little

Comment: But now you actually introduced another `if`. And with respect to readability, it is really hard to tell if this really does what it should do (even so that I think it is valid I need a long time to understand if that's true).

Comment: Ok the code logic is now different at another place. The code will also `"No such property"` if not element fulfills `contacts[i].firstName === name` but at least one element does not have the property `prop` but in that case `"No such contact"` has to be returned to be logically equivalent to the code of the OP.

Comment: @t.niese I agree with the fact that it isn't very readable, I guess I was focusing more on the _why is the second function not working correctly_ part of the question :P. I'll try and think of a better solution which is cleaner, but, in the meantime, I think Jamiec's answer is the way to go

Comment: Check that [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhpvc5t4/) that has the code of the OP and yours. I removed `number`  from `Potter`, now the outcome of your function and the one of the OP is different. I don't know if this is relevant or not for the OP (I even don't know if that was for the first version of your code). I just wanted to point out that they a logical different for the case that it is relevant for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very compact and readable code using `Array.find`, using roughly the same number of checks as in your first implementation (code simplified for readability):

```js
const arr = [
  {name: 'john', age: 42},
  {name: 'doe', age: 24},
];

const lookup = (name, prop) => {
  let found = arr.find(elt => elt.name==name);
  if (!found) return 'No such name';
  if (found && !found.hasOwnProperty(prop)) return 'No such property';
  return found;
}

console.log(
lookup('john', 'age'),
lookup('john', 'size'),
lookup('joe', 'age'),
lookup('joe', 'size'),
);
```

Comment: You do not really need the `found &&` in `if (found && !found.hasOwnProperty(prop))`, due to the `if (!found) return 'No such name';` in the previous line the `found` has to be truthy.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this. The problem in your code is, you return immediately if first item does not matched the condition.

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {  
  for ( i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {  
    if (contacts[i].firstName === name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      return contacts[i][prop];   
    }        
  }

  return "No such contact or property under contact";    
}
```

Comment: But isn't that what my first function does? It also returns immediately

Comment: yeah.. it returns only if valid match is found. in your function, it was returning in the first iteration itself. if match is found then valid value else "No such ...." string.

Comment: Hi mate if you can get chance please can you explain the difference in return structure between function 1 and function so that I clearly understand e.g.

Function 1: What it does and difference

Function 2: What it does and difference

Answer (score 0):

`return` statement in function/method stops executing rest of the code from your function. return means - Ok, i find my expected result - so my work is done :)

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {  

  var result = null;

  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) { 

    if (contacts[i].firstName === name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {                 
      return contacts[i][prop]     
    } else {
      result = "No such property"; 
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

**For multiple matching:**

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {  

  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) { 

    if (contacts[i].firstName === name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {                 
      result.push(contacts[i][prop]);     
    } else if(result == []) {
      result = "No such property"; 
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes"))
```

Comment: This change the logic of the code. If there are two elements with the `firstName` equal to `name` then and only first one in the list does not have the property `prop`, then the code of the OP will result in `No such property`, your code, however, would then return the second matching object.

Comment: @t.niese yes you are right. But my code will return the first matching object - not second. Look my edited answer please.

Comment: My complaint was not about your code returning only one element, the code of the OP does also only return one element. My complaint was if the `contacts` array is e.g. `[{firstName: "Harray"}, {firstName:"Harray", likes:2}]` then the code of the OP would result in `"No such property"` your code however returns `{firstName:"Harray", likes:2}`.